# Format too old or invalid type library in Chinese Excel 2010

Tags: c#, ms-office, vsto

Error came at Startup of Excel 2010 in Chinese MS Office .

> Error is as followS 
>          格式太旧或类型程序库无效 . (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80028018 (TYPE_E_INVDATAREAD)  )

Please Assist ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a well-known issue when automating Office applications. There are two possible ways to avoid the issue:

1. Use the late binding technology specifying the culture information when calling properties and methods, see [Type.InvokeMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.invokemember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.
2. Set the CultureInfo prior to calling any Excel properties or methods.

You can read more about that in the following articles (contains the same information):

- [BUG: "Old format or invalid type library" error when automating Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320369?wa=wsignin1.0)
- [BUG: “Old format or invalid type library” error when automating Excel (Christin Boyd)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2009/07/06/bug-old-format-or-invalid-type-library-error-when-automating-excel-christin-boyd.aspx)
- [HowTo: Fix “Old format or invalid type library” error (0x80028018)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/02/13/old-format-invalid-type-library/)